# Extension website statistics

Tags: web, statistics, google-chrome-extension

I want to create an extension that can keep a count of the websites that I visit and the number of times I visit each website.

I dont want t ouse the history API in order to get the statistics. I have tried the onUpdated event listener it just keeps on storing the websites whenever I shift tabs.

How can I do this ?

background.html :

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if(changeInfo.status == "complete")
  console.log(' url: ' + tab.url + ' change: ' + changeInfo.url);}
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by shifting tabs?

Comment: when I click on a different tab.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Can you show your code? Maybe you have some other extension installed that interfere?

Comment: When I switch tabs nothing happens (and shouldn't). If you are sure there is nothing in your extension that causes that then disable all installed extensions and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Create a google extension which adds a javascript counter to every page and then callback a server which collects the analytics data from the counter. Then you can use that database to create a website that can report on that data. I am just a newbie on this.